# How can I access Arrays that are generated via a function, and save in React state?

Tags: arrays, reactjs

I have some JSON data and I have multiple arrays that are generated from the following code by sorting the JSON data by a `Date` key:

```
function groupByDate(sortedData, date) {
            return sortedData.reduce((acc, curr) => {
                const key = curr[date];
                if (!acc[key]) {
                    acc[key] = [];
                }
                acc[key].push(curr);
                return acc;
            }, {});
        }

const dataByDate = groupByDate(sortedData, "Date");
console.log(dataByDate);
```

I can successfully log them to the console but would now like to save each one to its own state so I can access the data within React Render.

Is this possible, if so, how would I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You should check the [useState](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) hook

Comment: I have written classes for my project rather than functions. Do you have an example of how this could be done without using hooks?

Comment: Sure, use this.setState({dataByDate}) inside of your React class component

Comment: For some reason I thought it would be much harder than this! I use ```setState``` regularly throughout my application so I'm a little annoyed I didn't pick up on this!